# Should I worry about RSS urls for SEO?

Tags: url, rss, seo

Very quick question: should I worry about RSS urls for search engine optimization?

Can I just use an obscure ID number, or should it be as clean as an HTML document link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general consensus is that a URL should be clean, but a lot of people confuse this to mean that search engines will overlook a URL that isn't clean, and that they will put a large weighting on URL's that are packed full of keywords. There is no proof to show that this is accurate, despite what people say.

If a crawler finds your RSS feed then it'll crawl it as an RSS feed. You may want to clean the URL up for the sake of users to something that's easier for them to remember/type/etc.